# Lazy loading modules on specific port

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an application written in Python on Google App Engine which runs on port 8080 and loads my Angular app. Angular server runs on port 4200 and index page loads Angular resources like this:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/static/build/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/static/build/runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/static/build/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/static/build/styles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/static/build/vendor.js"></script>
```

Now that my Angular app has grown quite a bit, I want to refactor the code into modules and use lazy loading. Problem is that lazy loaded modules try to load on 8080 instead of 4200. My question is how do I configure the Angular app to load those modules on port 4200? I am using Angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below stackoverflow answers. This may be helpful to you. You can try following both a approaches.

1. [angular-cli-lazy-load-with-mvc5-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176297/angular-cli-lazy-load-with-mvc5-application?rq=1)
2. [Error while Lazy Loading Angular Modules With MVC5 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791994/error-while-lazy-loading-angular-modules-with-mvc5-application/53518488#53518488)